# How can I draw two rolling circles with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations

I tried to draw the picture on the left, but there was nothing I could do about the picture on the right.

It seems to be involved in the field of gear transmission.

It would be great if a warm-hearted friend could make an animation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,patterns.meta,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,1) circle [radius=1];
\draw (0,3) circle [radius=1];
\draw[-stealth] (-0.65,1.3) arc (-200:-260:0.6);
\draw[-stealth] (-0.65,2.7) arc (200:260:0.6);
\draw[{Circle[open, length=1mm]}-Stealth] (0,1) -- (0,0);
\draw[{Circle[open, length=1mm]}-Stealth] (0,3) -- (0,2);
\path[pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={4pt/sqrt(2)}]}] (-1.5,0) edge[thick] ++(3,0) 
rectangle ++ (3,-0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The PSTricks solution had been anticipated long time ago [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/420183/87876).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Compile with [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.io/).

picture 1

```
unitsize(1cm);
import patterns;

path c1=circle((0,1),1),c2=circle((0,3),1);
path arc1=arc((0,1),0.7,-200,-250);
path arc2=arc((0,3),0.7,200,250);

draw(c1^^c2);
draw(arc1,Arrow(size=3));
draw(arc2,Arrow(size=3));
draw((0,1)--(0,0),Arrow());
dot((0,1),FillDraw(white));
draw((0,3)--(0,2),Arrow());
dot((0,3),FillDraw(white));

add("yourpattern",hatch(2mm,dir(45)));
fill(box((-1.5,-0.2),(1.5,0)),pattern("yourpattern"));
draw((-1.5,0)--(1.5,0),0.7bp+black);
shipout(bbox(2mm,invisible));
```

[image]

picture 2

```
unitsize(1cm);
import patterns;
import graph;
path c1=circle((0,1),1),c2=circle((0,3),1);

draw(c1^^c2);

draw((0,1)--(0,1)+dir(-150),Arrow); 
draw((0,3)--(0,3)+dir(-30),Arrow); 
dot((0,1),FillDraw(white));
dot((0,3),FillDraw(white));

path arc1=arc((0,1),1,210,270), arc2=arc((0,1),1,30,90), arc3=arc((0,3),1,270,330);
path line1=(0,0)--(-length(arc1),0);

add("yourpattern",hatch(2mm,dir(45)));
fill(box((-1.5,-0.2),(1.5,0)),pattern("yourpattern"));
draw((-1.5,0)--(1.5,0),0.6bp+black);
draw(arc1^^line1,0.8bp+red);
draw(arc2^^arc3,0.8bp+blue);
shipout(bbox(2mm,invisible));
```

[image]

Animation. (**BAD CODE**)

```
import animate;
import patterns;
settings.tex="pdflatex"; 

animation Ani;
unitsize(1cm);
real t=6.284; // arclength(circle((0,1),1))=6.28406679229544
for(real a=0.0; a <= t; a=a+t/50)
{
save();
draw(circle((0+a,1),1)^^circle((0+a,3),1));

draw((0+a,1)--(0+a,1)+dir(-90-a*180/pi),Arrow());
draw((0+a,1)--(0+a,1)+dir(180+-90-a*180/pi),dashed+blue); 
draw((0+a,3)--(0+a,3)+dir(-90+a*180/pi),Arrow());
dot((0+a,1),FillDraw(white));
dot((0+a,3),FillDraw(white));

// L=alpha*pi*r/180 (wikipedia)

path arc1=(a != 0.0) ? arc((0+a,1),1,-90,-90-a*180/pi) : nullpath, // r=1
     arc2=(a != 0.0) ? arc((0+a,1),1,90,90-a*180/pi) : nullpath,
     arc3=(a != 0.0) ? arc((0+a,3),1,-90,-90+a*180/pi) : nullpath;
path line1=(a != 0.0) ? (0,0)--(a,0) : nullpath;

add("yourpattern",hatch(2mm,dir(45)));
fill(box((-1,-0.2),(1+t,0)),pattern("yourpattern"));
draw((-1,0)--(1+t,0),0.6bp+black);
draw(arc2^^arc3,0.8bp+blue);
draw(arc1^^line1,0.8bp+red);

if (a == t){
draw(circle((a,3),1),0.8bp+blue);
draw(circle((a,1),1),0.8bp+red);
}
Ani.add();
restore();
}
erase();
Ani.movie(BBox(2mm,invisible));
```

[image]

*Good animation.* (**RECOMMENDED**)

```
import animate;
import patterns;
settings.tex="pdflatex"; 

animation Ani;
unitsize(1cm);
real t=arclength(circle((0,1),1));
int iter=68;

for (int i=0; i <= iter; ++i)
{
save();
real a=i*t/iter;

draw((0+a,1)--(0+a,1)+dir(-90-a*180/pi),Arrow());
draw((0+a,1)--(0+a,1)+dir(180+-90-a*180/pi),dashed+blue); 
draw((0+a,3)--(0+a,3)+dir(-90+a*180/pi),Arrow());
dot((0+a,1),FillDraw(white));
dot((0+a,3),FillDraw(white));
add("yourpattern",hatch(2mm,dir(45)));
fill(box((-1,-0.2),(1+t,0)),pattern("yourpattern"));
draw((-1,0)--(1+t,0),0.6bp+black);

if (i == 0){
draw(circle((a,3),1));
draw(circle((a,1),1));
}
else if (i < iter){
draw(circle((a,3),1));
draw(circle((a,1),1));
// L=alpha*pi*r/180 (wikipedia)
path arc1=arc((0+a,1),1,-90,-90-a*180/pi), // r=1
     arc2=arc((0+a,1),1,90,90-a*180/pi),
     arc3=arc((0+a,3),1,-90,-90+a*180/pi);
path line1=(0,0)--(a,0);
draw(arc2^^arc3,0.6bp+blue);
draw(arc1^^line1,0.8bp+red);
}
else {
draw(circle((a,3),1),0.6bp+blue);
draw(circle((a,1),1),0.6bp+red);
draw((0,0)--(a,0),0.8bp+red);
}
Ani.add();
restore();
}
erase();
Ani.movie(BBox(2mm,invisible));
```

https://ezgif.com/pdf-to-gif

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Here is a [TiKZ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/TiKZ) solution that is a slightly enhanced version of the OP and is animated using

> convert -delay 5 -loop 0 -density 200 -background white -alpha remove file.pdf file.gif

to produce:

[image]

To get this from the MWE we first modify the code to allow the arrows to be at arbitrary angles, so that we have

[image]

Here is the modified `tikzpicture` from the MWE that produces this:

```
  \foreach \ang [evaluate=\ang as \dist using {(\ang-270)*pi/180}] in {270,265,...,-85} {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox (-3.2, -0.3) rectangle (3.2, 4.2);
      \draw (0,1) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (0,3) circle [radius=1];
      \draw[-stealth,red] (-0.65,1.3) arc (-200:-260:0.6);
      \draw[-stealth,blue] (-0.65,2.7) arc (200:260:0.6);
      \path[pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={4pt/sqrt(2)}]}]
             (-3,0) edge[thick] ++(6,0) rectangle ++ (6,-0.2);
      \draw[-Stealth]  (0,3)node[axel]{} -- ++({180-\ang}:1);
      \draw[-Stealth]  (0,1)node[axel]{} -- ++(\ang:1);
      \draw[red,thick] (0,0) -- ++ (\dist, 0);
      \draw[blue,thick](0,2) arc (270:540-\ang:1);
      \draw[blue,thick](0,2) arc (90:\ang-180:1);
      \draw[red,thick] (0,0) arc (270:\ang:1);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
```

The stationary version is a little distracting to watch but it already contains everything that we need to make the picture roll. The main difference between the stationary and the rolling version is that we need to shift the `x`-coordinates of most of the nodes by `\dist`. Here is the final code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,patterns.meta,decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{
  axel/.style = {circle, minimum width=1mm,inner sep=0pt, draw, fill=white}
}

\begin{document}
  \foreach \ang [evaluate=\ang as \dist using {(270-\ang)*pi/180}] in {270,265,...,-85} {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \useasboundingbox (-2, -0.3) rectangle (8, 4.2);
      \draw (\dist,1) circle [radius=1];
      \draw (\dist,3) circle [radius=1];
      \draw[-stealth,red] (\dist-0.65,1.3) arc (-200:-260:0.6);
      \draw[-stealth,blue] (\dist-0.65,2.7) arc (200:260:0.6);
      \path[pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={4pt/sqrt(2)}]}]
             (-1,0) edge[thick] ++(8,0) rectangle ++ (8,-0.2);
      \draw[-Stealth]  (\dist,3)node[axel]{} -- ++({180-\ang}:1);
      \draw[-Stealth]  (\dist,1)node[axel]{} -- ++(\ang:1);
      \draw[red,thick] (0,0)--(\dist,0);
      \draw[blue,thick](\dist,2) arc (270:540-\ang:1);
      \draw[blue,thick](\dist,2) arc (90:\ang-180:1);
      \draw[red,thick] (\dist,0) arc (270:\ang:1);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Interesting solution without animated package! is that code a cmd code for converting to gif?

Comment: Yes, you run this from the command line. The `convert` command is part of [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php). I learned this trick from a post by marmot, or their sobriquet Schrodinger's cat, back in the good old days when they graced these pages.

Answer (score 15):

The moving observers view, made with Ti*k*Z.

[image][image]

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
%\documentclass[dvisvgm]{standalone}
%\documentclass[export]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns.meta,arrows.meta}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{xsavebox} % xlrbox

\begin{document}
  \begin{xlrbox}{ground}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \path[pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={4pt/sqrt(2)}]}]
             (-1,0) edge[thick] ++(8,0) rectangle ++ (8,-0.2);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  \end{xlrbox}%
%
  \begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{20}
    \multiframe{181}{iAngle=270+-2}{
      \pgfmathsetmacro\dist{(270-\iAngle)*pi/180}%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[use as bounding box, clip] (\dist-2,-0.3) rectangle (\dist+2,4.2);
        \draw (\dist,1) circle [radius=1];
        \draw (\dist,3) circle [radius=1];
        \draw[-stealth,red] ($(\dist,1)+(\iAngle-110:0.65)$) arc (\iAngle-110:\iAngle-170:0.65);
        \draw[-stealth,blue] ($(\dist,3)+(110-\iAngle:0.65)$) arc (110-\iAngle:170-\iAngle:0.65);
        \node [anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt] at (-1,0) {\theground};
        \draw[dashed,blue] (\dist,1) -- ++(\iAngle-180:1);
        \draw[-Stealth] (\dist,1) -- ++(\iAngle:1);
          \filldraw[fill=white] (\dist,1) circle (0.5mm);
        \draw[-Stealth] (\dist,3) -- ++(180-\iAngle:1);
          \filldraw[fill=white] (\dist,3) circle (0.5mm);
        \draw[red,thick] (0,0)--(\dist,0);
        \draw[blue,thick](\dist,2) arc (-90:180-\iAngle:1);
        \draw[blue,thick](\dist,2) arc (90:\iAngle-180:1);
        \draw[red,thick] (\dist,0) arc (270:\iAngle:1);
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
  \end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 I toyed a little with using your [animate](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/animate) package but as I'd never used it before, and since I should be doing other things, I didn't try. This is a nice tutorial:)

Comment: Oh, thank you, @Andrew. Interestingly, in order to get the hatched ground move left and out of the viewport, it is necessary to save it in a PDF XObject (using the `xlrbox` environment from one of my other packages). A standard LaTeX savebox isn't enough. For some reason, the hatching stands still, similar to the second Gif of your answer.

Answer (score 12):

Like this? No animation.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,patterns.meta,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,1)coordinate(D) circle [radius=1];
\draw (0,3)coordinate(U) circle [radius=1];

\draw[{Circle[open, length=1mm]}-Stealth] (D) --++ (-150:1);
\draw[{Circle[open, length=1mm]}-Stealth] (U) --++ (-20:1);
\draw[densely dashed, blue] (D) --++ (30:1);
\draw [very thick, red] ([yshift=-1cm]D)coordinate(DD) arc (-90:-150:1);
\draw [very thick, blue] ([yshift=1cm]D) arc (90:30:1);
\draw [very thick, blue] ([yshift=-1cm]U) arc (-90:-20:1);

\path[pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={4pt/sqrt(2)}]}] (-1.5,0) edge[thick] ++(3,0) rectangle ++ (3,-0.2);
\draw [very thick, red] (DD)--++(180:0.9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]